# how to calculate eigenvalue and eigenvector without any library

Tags: python, data-science, pca, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I am trying to implementing PCA using pure Python code. I have a CSV file I read all columns and rows from CSV and change it to a matrix form then I have calculate and found mean and covariance of matrix, now I am trying to write a function to find the eigenvalue and eigenvector of my covariance matrix.

My question is how to solve this part to find the eigenvalue and eigenvector? For this step I have a function to find determinant of matrix but problem is with lambda symbol here its (x) --- (A-λI)=0.

Mean of Matrix

```
24   24   25   26   26
```

Covariance Matrix (sum(x-Xb) * (y - Yb))/n-1

```
175  151  162  173  172

151  185  177  177  177 

162  177  222  195  192 

173  177  195  234  200 

172  177  192  200  238
```

Identity Matrix

```
x    0    0    0    0   
0    x    0    0    0   
0    0    x    0    0   
0    0    0    x    0   
0    0    0    0    x   

175-x       151     162     173     172    
151       185-x   177     177     177    
162         177     222-x   195     192    
173         177     195     234-x   200
```

here is my code for determinant, now how to change the below code to calculate the above (A-λI) Matrix?

```
def getCofactor(mat,temp, p,q,n):

    i = 0
    j = 0
    for row in range(n):
        for col in range(n):
            if (row != p and col != q):
                temp[i][j] = mat[row][col]
                j+=1
                if (j == n - 1):
                    j = 0
                    i+=1
    return temp


def determinantOfMatrix(mat,n):

    D = 0 # Initialize result 
    if (n == 1):
        return mat[0][0]
    temp = [[[] for x in range(n)] for y in range(n)]
    sign = 1; 
    for f in range(n):
        getCofactor(mat, temp, 0, f, n) 
        D += sign * mat[0][f] * determinantOfMatrix(temp, n - 1); 
        sign = -sign; 
    return D
```

Comment: I'd take a look at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numerical_analysis_topics#Eigenvalue_algorithms and implement the simplest algorithm there. The way to solve this on paper is not the best for the computer.

Comment: As I am new in programming field it's difficult to write a function for solving this problem, I would be very happy if you can bring changes on the above code or give me some reference to write the function step by step .

Comment: For the simple case 2x2: [Finding Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors : 2 x 2 Matrix Example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IdsV0RaC9jM) (Youtube). More general: [FORTRAN Subroutines for Computing the Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors of a General Matrix by Reduction to General Tridiagonal Form](http://www.netlib.org/utk/people/JackDongarra/PAPERS/044_1992_ALGORITHM-710-FORTRAN-Subroutines-for-Computing-Eigenvalues.pdf), and for parallel processing: [New Complex Parallel Eigenvalue and Eigenvector Routines](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lawnspdf/lawn153.pdf)